# How do I prevent others from changing the status of my bot?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a `command` to change the `status` of the bot directly.

If I put the bot into other servers, those who have `administrator permissions` will be able to change the status of the bot, and I **don't want that**.

I want to be the **only one** beeing able to change the `status` of the bot.

This is my current code:

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
  var argresult = message.content.split(` `).slice(1).join(" ");
  const { member, mentions } = message;

  if (member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "wat")) {

      client.user.setActivity(argresult, { type: "WATCHING" });
      message.channel.send(
        "**:white_check_mark: | The Watching Status Has Been Changed To : ``" +
          `${argresult}` +
          "``**"
      );
      
      console.log(`Bot status was changed to: ${argresult}`);
    }
  } else {
    message.reply("You dont have permission to do that");
  }
});
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Please post code as text.

Comment: Post the code in the text so we can copy it

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just give yourself a very custom role that only you can have, and the code would go something like this:

In this case, you have to make a new role called "AdminDeveloper" and assign it to only you.

```
client.on('message', message => {
            var argresult = message.content.split(` `).slice(1).join(' ');
            const {
                member,
                mentions
            } = message;
            if (member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'AdminDeveloper') {
                    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'wat')) {
                        client.user.setActivity(argresult, {
                            type: 'WATCHING'
                        });
                        message.channel.send("**:white_check_mark: | The Watching Status Has Been Changed To : ``" + `${argresult}` + "``**");
                        console.log(`Bot status was changed to: ${argresult}`);
                    }
                } else {
                    message.reply("You dont have permission to do that")
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is [here in the discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/faq.html#how-do-i-limit-a-command-to-a-single-user)

You restrict the command so that only you can do it by rejecting anyone who doesn't have your user id

```
if (<message>.author.id === '<id>') {
    // This is if they are you
}


// or you can do which is the opposite, it returns if it is not you
if (<message>.author.id != '<id>') return
```